# Why are the columns in the matplotlib histogram not on top of the numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I would expect every column to be centered on top of their bin number. Instead, the 1 and 2 bars are right of the number, the 3rd on to the left. Why is it not even consistent?

[image: histogram plot]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

degrees = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
plt.hist(degrees)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: *It is not supposed to, use [plt.bar()](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) instead. For longer explanation, please read below.*

#### Why bars are not on top of numbers 1,2&3?

The purpose of a *histogram* is to approximate the *distribution* of the data. For example

```py
import numpy as np
plt.hist(np.random.normal(3, 7, 100))
```

which gives

[image]

Now, when you have much less data, which is integer valued, and call

```py
plt.hist([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3])
```

you also get approximation of the distribution of the data you provided. With the default parameters it looks like this:

[image]

The [documentation of hist](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) tells that

- If you do not provide `bins`, it will default to 10.
- If you do not provide `range`, it will default to min and max of your data

Therefore, your data will be put inside 10 bins, with min at `1` and max at `3`. These bins will be

```
In [45]: np.linspace(1,3, 11)
Out[45]: array([1. , 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2. , 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 2.8, 3. ])
```

**Since you have only data inside bins `1.0 - 1.2`, `2.0 - 2.2` and `2.8 - 3.0`, you will see three bars centered at `1.1`, `2.1` and `2.9`.**

#### A guess of what you're after

If your data is integer (categorical) valued, like

```
degrees = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

and you want to know the relative sizes of these categories, you probably want to create a [**bar plot**](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) instead.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter

degrees = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
counts = Counter(degrees)

plt.bar(counts.keys(), counts.values())
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't specify the bins. If you add the bins in:

```
degrees = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
plt.hist(degrees, bins=[1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
```

[image]